# Why isn't org-agenda skipping DONE tasks?

Tags: org-mode, init-file, org-agenda

I'm trying to set up a planning process for the day (like in http://newartisans.com/2007/08/using-org-mode-as-a-day-planner/), but my org-agenda keeps showing DONE tasks, even though I set org-agenda-skip-deadline-if-done and org-agenda-skip-scheduled-if-done in the init.el:

[image: org-agenda and init.el view]

My current init.el file is available at https://github.com/aylons/emacsd/blob/master/init.el

Comment: Judging from the fact that the `DONE`  face and the `TODO` face look the same above, I'm guessing that your `org-todo-keywords` are screwed up, so Org mode does not know that it is done. Do `C-h v org-todo-keywords RET` and add it to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting from my comment:

> Judging from the fact that the DONE face and the TODO face look the same above, I'm guessing that your org-todo-keywords are screwed up, so Org mode does not know that it is done.

So I checked your init file and I see this:

```el
...
'(org-todo-keywords
   '((sequence "TODO(t)" "DONE(d)" "WAITING(w)" "SOMEDAY(s)" "NEXT(s)")))
...
```

So indeed your `org-todo-keywords` setting is wrong: you need to move the `DONE` entry to the last place:

```
...lang-el
...
'(org-todo-keywords
   '((sequence "TODO(t)" "WAITING(w)" "SOMEDAY(s)" "NEXT(s)" "DONE(d)")))
...
```

The doc string for `org-todo-keywords` (`C-h v org-todo-keywords RET`) says:

> Each sequence starts with a symbol, either ‘sequence’ or ‘type’,
> indicating if the keywords should be interpreted as a sequence of
> action steps, or as different types of TODO items.  The first
> keywords are states requiring action - these states will select a headline
> for inclusion into the global TODO list Org produces.  If one of the
> "keywords" is the vertical bar, "|", the remaining keywords
> signify that no further action is necessary.  If "|" is not found,
> the last keyword is treated as the only DONE state of the sequence.

So to be absolutely sure, it's probably best to include a "|" element in the list. That's necessary if you have more than one `DONE` state, but it's good practice in general:

```el
...
'(org-todo-keywords
   '((sequence "TODO(t)" "WAITING(w)" "SOMEDAY(s)" "NEXT(s)" "|" "DONE(d)")))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just changed it and it worked beautifully. I've been using emacs for a long time, but only now I'm trying to set it up and understand things better.